# how to use curl request json to login to remote site

Tags: php, json, curl

I had done this:

```
 <?php 
       $post_body = '{"login": "injoit", "password": "injoit"}';
       $cookie_file = tempnam('/temp', 'cookie');
       $ch = curl_init('remote server login here');

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_body);
       curl_exec($ch);
```

I am getting this in response : `Failed to connect to "remote server url here" port 8002: Connection timed out(7)`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   $cookie_file = tempnam('./temp', 'cookie');
   $post_fields = '{"login": "injoit", "password": "injoit"}';
   $ch = curl_init('http://api.quickblox.com/login.json');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
   curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Also need to give `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $CookieJarFilename);` 
 to save the sessionID which the remote server gives you as a client

Comment: I had edited my question as your answer. But still not working. Please help

Comment: @Aashi Also @jaxon updated his answer  please be sure the set the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and the cookie_file path which sould be permited to write who uses this php script